# Good popular informative video guides to human anatomy?

Tags: anatomy, internal-organs, video

Can you recommend visually illustrative, but still scientifically justified video guides with exhaustive commentary to organs and/or systems of the human body? I'd like to familiarize myself with human anatomy.

Comment: Your question is not a question. Also does "popular" matter or is only "informative" enough? I would ask "What are good informative videos explaining human anatomy?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Free videos with subtitles:**

[Introduction to Anatomy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6rZw7QkGLw): basic anatomical terms, planes, positions, directions..a single 20 min video

[Kenhub](https://www.kenhub.com/en/dashboard), comprehensive, organized, with basic anatomical terms, medical imaging, also histology, premium account available with quizzes and study questions

[Anatomy Zone](http://anatomyzone.com/), also available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=anatomy%20zone): 190+ videos, maybe not organized best

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/): anatomy + physiology combined

[Innerbody](https://www.innerbody.com/htm/body.html): interactive images with detailed description